# Using MySqlBulkLoader to upload a DataSet content : Issue with the filename

Tags: c#, mysql

I'd like to try the performance of MySqlBulkLoader knowing that the Adapter.update() method i'm using is taking roughly 30 mn to run.
I understand you have to go through a file to do it so here is my code :

```
        private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\Utilisateur\ds.txt";
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in Globals.ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    string itemstr = item.ToString();
                    sw.Write((string)itemstr + "\t");
                }
                sw.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(Globals.connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE Song",conn);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn)
            {
                TableName = Globals.ds.Tables[0].ToString(),
                Timeout = 600,
                FieldTerminator = "\t",
                LineTerminator = "\n",
                FileName = fileName
            };
            var numberOfInsertedRows = bl.Load();
            Console.WriteLine(numberOfInsertedRows);
        }
    }
```

The file is generated ok. but at the `var numberOfInsertedRows = bl.Load();`  line, i have the following error at run time :

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Can't get stat of '/var/packages/MariaDB10/target/mysql/disk/C:\Users\Utilisateur\ds.txt' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")'

I tried to put "/" instead of "\" in the fileName but it's the same error.

I have no idea what's going on, anyone can help ?

Thanks

Comment: You can only add Utilisateur/ds.txt to the bulk  as filename, and you should also store there your file. Besides naming your variables like the objects is very confuising

Comment: sorry i didnt understand what you mean by add to the bulk as filename, can you please explain ? i tried to change location but it's not the issue it seems. Thanks

Comment: string fileName = @"C:\Users\Utilisateur\ds.txt";  can't be used in your                 LineTerminator = "\n",
                FileName = fileName   it is looking for a rfile in '/var/packages/MariaDB10/target/mysql/disk/

Comment: ok then i replaced the string fileName with the value ie @"C:/Users/Utilisateur/Music/ds.txt" and i have the same error. It's crazy all the example i'm able to see on StackFlow are doing the same way. what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `MySqlBulkLoader` loads a file from the *server's* file system. To use a local file, set `bl.Local = true;` before calling `bl.Load()`.

To enable this, you will need to set `AllowLoadLocalInfile = True` in your connection string; see https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/load-data-local-infile/

Finally, if you switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), you can use its [`MySqlBulkCopy` API](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysql-bulk-copy/) to load data directly from a `DataTable`, instead of first saving it to a local CSV file, then loading that file.

Comment: Thanks Bradley, it's perfect :) :) Works like a charm, the population of the DB takes seconds vs 30 minutes :) I havent investigated yet the API to load from a Datatable but i will right now :) thanks

Comment: Well i wasnt that successfull implementing the MysqlBulkCopy ... I'll post another question. nothing's easy pfff :)